# showing only current user's relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have 2 entities, User and courses, each student can have many courses and each course can have many students. Anyway, I'm trying to make it so that when a user connects to his account, it shows him all the courses he's related to. I know I have to do it from my controller but how do I get only the ones he's related to.
my entities

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Courses", mappedBy="Users")
     */
    private $courses;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->courses = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * @return Collection|course[]
     */
    public function getCourses(): Collection
    {
        return $this->courses;
    }

    public function addCourse(Course $course): self
    {
        if (!$this->courses->contains($course)) {
            $this->courses[] = $course;
            $course->addUser($this);
            return $this;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCourse(Course $course): self
    {
        if ($this->courses->contains($course)) {
            $this->courses->removeElement($course);
            $course->removeUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CourseRepository")
 */
class Course
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=55)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\user", inversedBy="courses")
     */
    private $users;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setname(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }



    /**
     * @return Collection|user[]
     */
    public function getUser(): Collection
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function addUser(user $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(user $user): self
    {
        if ($this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users->removeElement($user);
        }

        return $this;
    }


}
```

Comment: This question is pretty similar to your previous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923233/submiting-data-in-a-manytomany-relation and as already said by @AkenRoberts in your previous "How are you trying to access the data? You've shown us the entities, but not how you're using them." Also it is difficult to understand (for me at least) what you want to achieve without a clear example.

Comment: I kinda got the answer to that question and forgot to answer Aken, sorry about that. To explain what I'm trying to do, each user (student) has an account and he can have many courses he's related to (done by the admin). when the student connects to his account, he's greeted by a list of the courses he's related to. Until now, I still can't find a solution for that as I don't know how to only get the courses related to that student that's currently logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, because you apparently have a bi-directional relationship (inversedBy and mappedBy) you dont need to do anything special. Doctrine has already done this. Just grab the user in the controller:

```
// Once you have a protected controller route,
// you can use $this->getUser() from inside the
// controller action to access the current authenticated user.

$user = $this->getUser();
```

And iterate as you'd like through their related courses:

```
foreach ($user->getCourses() as $course) {

}
```

Because `getCourses` also returns a `Collection` instance, you can also use the `->map` and `->filter` functions that ship with the Collection class...